# How to partition graph on vertex degree. And count the number of edges with same end vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Step-I   Input a graph and generate Table
How to partition graph on vertex degree. And count the number of edges with same end vertices as given in table given below. The program also shows the graph and its generated table. The table values are put in the given formula and get a number given below.

[image]

Comment: Your graph has a mistake. There is a '2' which should be a '3' in the pentagonal part in the middle, if indeed those numbers are supposed to represent degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by "edges of the same kind"?

Answer (score 1):

```
(* You need to specify a graph first *)
g = Graph[{
   UndirectedEdge["a", "b"],
   UndirectedEdge["b", "c"],
   UndirectedEdge["c", "d"],
   UndirectedEdge["d", "e"],
   UndirectedEdge["c", "f"],
   UndirectedEdge["d", "g"],
   UndirectedEdge["g", "h"],
   UndirectedEdge["h", "f"],
   UndirectedEdge["h", "i"],
   UndirectedEdge["i", "j"],
   UndirectedEdge["f", "k"],
   UndirectedEdge["k", "l"],
   UndirectedEdge["k", "m"],
   UndirectedEdge["k", "n"]
   }, VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]

getKind[edge_] := Sort[VertexDegree[g, #] & /@ (edge /. UndirectedEdge -> List)]

result = Tally[getKind /@ EdgeList[g]];
Grid[Transpose@result, Frame -> All]
```

[image]