# How we can find neighborhood degree sum vertices and find count edges of same end vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am new in Mathematica.  I want to draw a graph then add the degree of neighborhood vertices and generate a graph with neighborhood vertices sum degree. At next step I want to count edges of neighborhood[image] degree sum vertex with same NBH degree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to partition graph on vertex degree. And count the number of edges with same end vertices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300631/how-to-partition-graph-on-vertex-degree-and-count-the-number-of-edges-with-same)