# How to generate a graph and label all vertices with eccentricity of each vertex and then count the edges of generated graph with same end vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to generate a graph. Add degree of neighborhood vertex. and count the edges of edges with same end vertices of the graph.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to partition graph on vertex degree. And count the number of edges with same end vertices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300631/how-to-partition-graph-on-vertex-degree-and-count-the-number-of-edges-with-same)